# Decoding and Encoding Strings and Arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

In XCode beta 4 this code not only compiled, encoding and decoding an object gave back an identical instance.

```
public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    name = aDecoder.decodeObjectOfClass(NSString.self, forKey: SerializationKey.name) as String
    practiseDeals = aDecoder.decodeObjectOfClass(NSArray.self, forKey: SerializationKey.practiseDeals) as [BridgeDealBiddingPractise]
    seat = aDecoder.decodeObjectOfClass(BridgePlayer.self, forKey: SerializationKey.seat) as BridgePlayer
}
```

Installing beta 5 there are link errors that `__TFSS18bridgeToObjectiveCfSSFT_CSo8NSString` is undefined. According to the release notes bridgeToObjectiveC is to be retired, so I believe I should work out how to specify the class for a Swift string and Swift array. If you say that is documented somewhere I believe you, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Your code compiles for me in beta 5 (after creating dummy classes for the missing classes). The code you show doesn't use the `bridgeToObjectiveC` function either.

Comment: My code compiles correctly, it is a link error. Did you manage to execute it?

Comment: I did finally get time to look at this again. `$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` had disappeared from the framework search path. :(